# fuzzy join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone could shed some light for me on my issue.

I need to be able to join the following two tables together in SQL

Values in table 1 for some column

```
QWERTY10
QAZWSXEDCR10
QAZWSXED1230
```

Values in table 2 for some column

```
QWWERTY20
QAZWSXEDCR20
QAZWSXED1240
```

the result that I need is

```
QWERTY100000 QWERTY200000

QAZWSXEDCR10 QAZWSXEDCR20

QAZWSXED1230 QAZWSXED1240
```

Now, for QWERTY10000 to be linked to QWERTY20000 I need to do the join on the first 6 characters of the value in the field
but for the QAZWSXEDCR10 to be linked to QAZWSXEDCR20 I need to do a join on the first 10 characters of the value in the field. If I do a join on the first 6 characters only then I will get duplicates. I will have smth like this:

```
QAZWSXEDCR10 QAZWSXEDCR20

QAZWSXEDCR10 QAZWSXED1240

QAZWSXED1230 QAZWSXEDCR20

QAZWSXED1230 QAZWSXED1240
```

and I also need `QAZWSXED1230` to be linked to `QAZWSXED1240` and there I need to do a join on 8 characters to make it work.

im having a hard time to figure out how to join my data together. I would like to avoid doing 10 different joins each based on a different number of characters.
eg do a join on 6 characters first and if not successful then do the join on 7, 8, 9 and 10. - there must be a different way...

Can someone recommend a solution here?

KR

Comment: Is it always letters? You can use PatIndex to find the first numbers location, then use substring to join up to that character? Busy now but can post a try at lunch

Comment: it can be letters, numbers and in rare occasions some special characters too

I am looking forward to reading your reply 
thx

Comment: I think what @Milney was asking was whether there is a consistent type of character that *shouldn't* match.  i.e. Do you just want the letter portion to match, but not the numeric, or should the numeric/special characters sometimes match too?

Comment: I mean is it always just the letters and special characters you would like to join on? I.e. UP UNTIL the numbers appear?

Comment: thx for the explanation - 90 % of cases it will be just letters that id like to join on. But the rule is I need to be able to find the second most similar value matching my original value. It is possible, although it happens rarely, that I would need to do the join on numbers and some other special characters too.

eg i have this in table 1 
QWERT10%10

and I have this in table 2
QWERT10%20

what I would like to see then is QWERT10%10 linked to QWERT10%20

so as you can see the match would have to include numbers and the percentage sign too

Comment: So does this mean there can be 2 records in table 2 that would match if you only used the text portion? e.g. table1 has `QWERT10%10` and table 2 has both `QWERT10%20` and `QWERT10%30`? If this is the case, do you want to match on both records?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Milney's comment, [PatIndex](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) may help by finding the string location of the first number - or special character if applicable.  You can then construct a substring of the matching portions of the strings

```
select  table1.col as col1,
        table2.col as col2
from    table1
        inner join
        table2
        on substring( table1.col, 1, patindex( '[0-9]', table1.col ) ) =
           substring( table2.col, 1, patindex( '[0-9]', table2.col ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of Alex's answer, just to handle the case where one or both values do not contain a digit:

```
select t1.col as col1, t2.col as col2
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on left(t1.col, patindex('%[0-9]%', t1.col+'0')) = left(t2.col, patindex('%[0-9]%', t2.col+'0'));
```

Comment: Excellent improvement!  I realised that I left the closing brackets of the `substring` out of my original answer though.  Can you update? Stackoverflow didn't accept an edit of less than 6 characters from me.

Comment: I tried your query but it retrieves a Cartesian product

WITH TT AS 
(
SELECT 
N'QWERTY10' AS Col
UNION ALL
SELECT
N'QAZWSXEDCR10' AS Col
UNION ALL
SELECT
N'QAZWSXED1230'AS Col

), TT2
AS 
(

SELECT 
N'QWWERTY20' AS Col
UNION ALL
SELECT 
N'QAZWSXEDCR20' AS Col
UNION ALL
SELECT 
N'QAZWSXED1240' AS col
)

select t1.col as col1, t2.col as col2,
left(t1.col, patindex('[0-9]', t1.col+'0')),
left(t2.col, patindex('[0-9]',t2.col+'0'))
from tt t1 inner join
     tt2 t2
     on left(t1.col, patindex('[0-9]', t1.col+'0')) = left(t2.col, patindex('[0-9]',t2.col+'0'))

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will help

```
Create table #table1 ( strValue varchar(100) ) 
Create table #table2 ( strValue varchar(100) ) 


Insert Into #table1 ( strValue ) Values
('QWERTY10'), ('QAZWSXEDCR10'),('QAZWSXED1230')

Insert Into #table2 ( strValue ) Values
('QWERTY20'), ('QAZWSXEDCR20'),('QAZWSXED1240')


Declare @MaxlengthT1 int, @MaxlengthT2 int
SELECT @MaxlengthT1 =  MAX(LEN(strValue)) FROM #table1
SELECT @MaxlengthT2 =  MAX(LEN(strValue)) FROM #table2


select  a.strValue  + REPLICATE('0',@MaxlengthT1 - LEN(a.strValue)) as col1,
        b.strValue  + REPLICATE('0',@MaxlengthT1 - LEN(b.strValue)) as col2
from    #table1 a 
        inner join
        #table2 b
        on substring( a.strValue, 0, patindex( '%[0-9]%', a.strValue )) =
           substring( b.strValue, 0, patindex( '%[0-9]%', b.strValue ))

DROP TABLE #table1 
DROP TABLE #table2
```

Comment: thanks
I appreciate your help a lot.

I am not too eager to use any function in my ON clause but I think there is no other way to do it

KR

Comment: hi guys

can you please tell me if there is a way I can rewrite this query so that I could get a match between these values?

SCRUMTH25K
SCRUMOH210LK

using '%[A-Z][0-9]%' will give me 6
if I then join the columns on the first 6 characters the join wont work because SCRUMT <> SCRUMO

i need something that can find two most similar values - is this even possible with PatIndex?